# Drag Drop using extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, placeholder

I want to implement drag and drop UI using extjs which should be exactly similar to http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

try implement using portal layout.

chkek [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qTuaU/)

refer [example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/portal/portal.html)

Comment: Seems like portal uses panels to implement the behavior... I am supposed to use ul-li elements and horizontal movement...
Any thoughts ??
please post the sample code if you can.....thanks